# Finding an old version of an eclipse feature

Tags: eclipse, plugins, helios, buckminster

I need org.eclipse.equinox.executable.3.4.1 feature jar specifically to create my eclipse plugin product.

I am using Buckminster to resolve dependencies. In my feature I have specified version 3.4.1 exactly to be able to query the repository for that version only. And my rmap is as follows.

```
<searchPath name="target.platform.online">
    <provider componentTypes="eclipse.feature,osgi.bundle"
        readerType="p2" source="false" mutable="false">
        <uri format="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios" />
    </provider>
    <provider componentTypes="eclipse.feature,osgi.bundle"
        readerType="p2" source="false" mutable="false">
        <uri format="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6" />
    </provider>
</searchPath>
```

When no specific version is provided, using the repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios provides 3.4.2. For the specific 3.4.1 version, dependency resolution ends with error as 3.4.1 cannot be found in the repository. Where can the version 3.4.1 be found or if they exist also in the same repository what kind of configuration is needed to be able to query an old version?

Update: I couldn't find the update site that includes the 3.4.1 version but under Equinox [download page](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/) release 3.6.1 contains the org.eclipse.equinox.executable feature version 3.4.1.

Knowing which eclipse update site contain this feature would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the feature you are looking for is still present in the the Helios update site but old version are hidden by default from the Eclipse installation UI.
To see previous versions, uncheck "Show only latest versions of available software".

Comment: Thanks but actually I am using Buckminster to materialize dependencies from the eclipse update site. I am not using the eclipse Update Manager from the IDE. I have updated the question.

Comment: Ok but this does not change the fact that the feature you are looking for is still present in the Helios update site. What you need to do is mark a strict dependence on a given version of the feature to help buckminster finding it.

Comment: Yes but I mentioned in my updated question. I have already fixed the version that I am looking for in the included features list of my feature. May be somehow I need to let Buckminster also to check for old versions from the repository?

Comment: I don't think so, but maybe you have another component that is automatically resolved to its last version and by transitivity add dependencies on the last version of your feature. Do you have any error messages?

Comment: Nothing but "No component match was found" message for both repositories given in the rmap